# The data edited in Slate.js editor saved as [Object],[Object] in the data based.How to make this Object as meaningful content?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, slate.js, uudecode

I am using a framework of slate.js named slate-plugins to build an editor. It worked to save the data in the database but the data saved as [Obj],[Obj] in the database instead of HTML data. Hence on calling the data at the frontend it is showing as [Obj][Obj] and not the actual content that I wrote.What should I do now

Answer (score 0):

Your database (probably) can only store strings. So you have to serialize it before the save using `JSON.stringify(value)`.

When you need to do the opposite operation, use `JSON.parse(value_from_database)` to get an object Slate can understand.